# Pyinstaller exe not saving output file on another PC

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller, exe

I have created a python executable file as tool.exe using pyinstaller which is taking a file as input and outputs a csv file. The tool.exe file is working fine on my pc and saving the csv file, but it is not saving csv file if running on any other computer (same Specs as mine, having python installed as well). On other PCs, it takes the input files and then nothing happens.

I'm saving csv file using the following line of code.

Data.to_csv('Output.csv')

and creating the file with this command:

pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "C:\Alldata\Box\Tool\Tool_2.py;." --add-data "C:\Alldata\Box\Tool\main.py;."  tool.py

I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I want output csv to be saved whenever I run exe file in any of the computers.

Comment: It's possible you are running into an error. I'd recommend looking into the `logging` module to log to file when you're running the exe file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the one dir mode as it is way faster as far as your question goes there must be an error popping up when you are running your exe first try the console mode as any error will be showed in the console once the error is decoded then use the both oneFile mode and windowed mode

Comment: I figured out what the issue is. When I'm running the exe in any other computer it is giving error for the numpy module as:
"Import error. bad magic number in numpy"
Now I don't know how to resolve this error.  There is no such error when running the exe on my PC.